# can't connect to ejabberd through Kaiwa chat client using websocket

Tags: websocket, xmpp, ejabberd

I can't connect to my ejabberd server through Kaiwa chat client. this is my ejabberd server configuration:

```
hosts:
  - "myserver.com"
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    certfile: "/Applications/ejabberd-15.10/conf/myserver.pem"
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    captcha: false
```

and this is my Kaiwa config file:

```
{
   "isDev": true,
   "http": {
       "host": "localhost",
       "port": 8000
   },
   "server": {
       "domain": "myserver.com",
       "wss": "wss://myserver.com:5280/websocket/"
   }
}
```

when I try to login I get this error:

WebSocket connection to 'wss://myserver.com:5280/websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

My ejabberd version is 15.10 which should support websocket.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was chrome and Safari. I am not sure why but the client app works perfectly with Mozilla Firefox but does not connect through Safari or Chrome. It could be a security setting.
Anyway, switching to mozilla solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

While you've specified the `certfile` option for `ejabberd_http`, this is not enough to activate encryption (as requested by using `wss://` instead of `ws://`).  You also need to specify the `tls` option:

```
hosts:
  - "myserver.com"
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    certfile: "/Applications/ejabberd-15.10/conf/myserver.pem"
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    captcha: false
    tls: true
```

Comment: I have tried with both wss and ws. I set tls to true in my ejabberd but still the same error

Comment: No error! but I get some warnings:

eldap:handle_info:709 LDAP server closed the connection: myserver.com:389

Comment: Hm, then I'm not sure what's going on. You might have some luck capturing the network traffic with tcpdump or Wireshark, to see if the Kaiwa client actually makes a connection, how far it gets, and if it gets dropped by the client or the server.